# Url encoding issue with Jersey Client

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I need to make a service call such as this:
http://myservice.com/path?var1=value1&var2=value2

The issue I have is value1 and value2 ends up getting encoded, and this makes the service call fail. For example, value1 is something like "a=b&b=c;2&&="... it contains special characters, basically.

I am guessing that this is an issue for the service to fix - to properly handle decoding encoded characters, which I do not think it is currently doing.

Here is a sample of how I am making these requests:

```
WebTarget target = client.target("http://test.com")
    .path("path1")
    .queryParam("var1", var1);
Builder builder = target.request();
...
```

What's puzzling to me is that if I make the same request just using Chrome, everything works. So that makes me to believe that I should have some way with the Jersey API of "disabling" the encoding.

Answer (score 6):

Only way I have found so far to use "raw" Url is to use URI.
So call like this

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost/~Common~0#/edit?vadf&&sfs&&fdsfd=fs&fsd");
WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
```

You get request url

```
1 > GET http://localhost/~Common~0#/edit?vadf&&sfs&&fdsfd=fs&fsd
```

Everything else I tried resulted in encoding special characters.