# Specify raw query string when using WebTarget

Tags: java, api, groovy, javax.ws.rs

I'm working with a large existing project, which utilises `javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget` to talk to RESTful API. The API is developed by a third party and I have no control over it. I need to make a request in the following format:

```
https://end.point.url/endpoint/id?data
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to specify such request using `WebTarget`. I tried using `path("endpoint/id?data")`, but this gets converted into `endpoint/id%3Fdata` and I get 404 back.  I tried using `queryParam` specifying empty value, which gets me `endpoint/id?data=` - which results in error *required parameter `data` missing*.

What other option is there? Replacing WebTarget with something else isn't feasible, as it is all over the large project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, related question: [Url encoding issue with Jersey Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260836/url-encoding-issue-with-jersey-client)

After quite a bit of research, it seems that the only way to do it is to specify the entire uri when the WebTarget is created, like so:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(authFeature);
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://end.point.url/endpoint/id?data")
```